# Why does Perl's JSON module not read or write files?

Tags: perl, json

Am I missing anything, or does [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) lacks a `write_to_file()` and `read_from_file()` subroutines?

Obviously, I can easily implement them, but as they seem so handy I wonder how can it be they are not there.

Comment: JSON lets you do the whole file management (open, check permission, error handling) the way you want. This way you can store/read objects in/from DB, network connection, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, it lacks a `write_to_file()` and `read_from_file()` function because usually, you don't store JSON in files but use it only to send data back to the web client. You've got to implement it by yourself, which, as you said correctly, isn't that much to do.

Answer (score 6):

```
use JSON;

sub read_from_file {
my $json;
{
  local $/; #Enable 'slurp' mode
  open my $fh, "<", "data_in.json";
  $json = <$fh>;
  close $fh;
}
return decode_json($json);
}

sub write_to_file {
my $data  = shift;
open my $fh, ">", "data_out.json";
print $fh encode_json($data);
close $fh;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would have been nice.